# How can i get the type of a polymorphic function for a specific type class instance?

Tags: haskell, ghci, lambdabot

For example, typing `:t ap` in GHCi gives the result

```
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

If I already know the Monad instance I'm going to use is `((->) r)`, how can I query for the type of `ap` for that specific instance?

Comment: If you only want to know functional types, there's [`Data.Aviary.Functional`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-aviary-0.4.0/docs/Data-Aviary-Functional.html). As for your question, you could try using TypeApplications to pass in a specific `m` tyvar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [visible type application](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#visible-type-application) feature to specify parametric types. You can look at functions in more creative way: functions in *Haskell* can be applied to not only values of some types, but also to types of that values. But to pass type you should somehow specify (with prepending `@`) that you're passing types (because types are not first-class objects in *Haskell* yet).

So here how it works:

```
λ: :set -XTypeApplications
λ: :t ap @((->) Int)
ap @((->) Int) :: (Int -> a -> b) -> (Int -> a) -> Int -> b
```

The only limitation of such approach is that you can't use type variables in `ghci`, you should use specific types (`Int` instead of `r`) but this is not big deal.

**ADVANCED SECTION**

Well, actually you can, but it's tricky:

```
λ: :set -XExplicitForAll 
λ: :set -XPartialTypeSignatures 
λ: :set -XScopedTypeVariables 
λ: :{
λ| foo :: forall r . _
λ| foo = ap @((->) r)
λ| :}
<interactive>:28:19: warning: [-Wpartial-type-signatures]
    • Found type wildcard ‘_’
        standing for ‘(r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b’
λ: :t foo
foo :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b
```

**UPD:** You can actually use placeholders instead of type variables (see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999199/how-can-i-get-the-type-of-a-polymorphic-function-for-a-specific-type-class-insta/43000286#43000286)). But if you want to specify exact names use approach from above.

```
λ: :t ap @((->) _)
ap @((->) _) :: (t -> a -> b) -> (t -> a) -> t -> b
```

**/ADVANCED SECTION**

One more thing to say about this approach: you should do something more if your functions have several type parameters and you want to specify exact one. Types are passed one by one from left to right just as simple arguments in some function like `bar :: Int -> String -> Double`. If you want to fix first argument of `bar` you should write `bar 5` and if you want to fix second, then, well, you can write something like `\n -> bar n "baz"` but this doesn't work with type application. You need to know two things:

1. Order of types.
2. How to specify desired type.

Consider next function:

```
λ: :t lift
lift :: (Monad m, MonadTrans t) => m a -> t m a
```

We want be able to specify `m` and `t` type variables. Because *Haskell* has no named type variables (yet) you **can't** write `:t lift {t=MaybeT}` or `:t lift {m=IO}` unfortunately. So go back to two things.

To see order of types you should use some compiler options. Order of type arguments is specified by `forall` and you can do it manually. Otherwise type parameters will be sorted somehow by the compiler. Mere mortals can't see order of types for `lift` function but if you're aware of some high-level magic you can:

```
λ: :set -fprint-explicit-foralls
λ: :t lift
lift
  :: forall {t :: (* -> *) -> * -> *} {a} {m :: * -> *}.
     (Monad m, MonadTrans t) =>
     m a -> t m a
```

And then you should use `@_` to skip some types:

```
λ: :t lift @MaybeT
lift @MaybeT
  :: forall {a} {m :: * -> *}. Monad m => m a -> MaybeT m a
λ: :t lift @_ @IO
lift @_ @IO
  :: forall {t :: (* -> *) -> * -> *} {a}.
     MonadTrans t =>
     IO a -> t IO a
λ: :t lift @_ @_ @Int
lift @_ @_ @Int
  :: forall {t :: (* -> *) -> * -> *} {t1 :: * -> *}.
     (Monad t1, MonadTrans t) =>
     t1 Int -> t t1 Int
```

Well, this is really mystery for me why `m` is shown as *third* argument in `forall` but should be passed as *second* but I'm still not aware of all magic.

Answer (score 12):

As [Lazersmoke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2892792/lazersmoke) said as a comment you can use the [TypeApplications](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication) extension that was introduced in GHC 8.0.

In GHCi:

```hs
λ > :set -XTypeApplications
λ > import Control.Monad
λ > :t ap @((->) _)
ap @((->) _) :: (t -> a -> b) -> (t -> a) -> t -> b
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a hack, but you could always do something like:

```
:t ap . (id :: ((->) r a) -> ((->) r a))
```

or

```
:t \x y -> (id :: ...) (ap x y)
```

interestingly

```
Prelude Control.Monad> type Reader = (->) r
Prelude Control.Monad> :t ap . (id :: Reader r a -> Reader r a)
ap . (id :: Reader r a -> Reader r a)
  :: Reader r (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b
```

differs from

```
Prelude Control.Monad> :t \x y -> (id :: Reader r a -> Reader r a) (ap x y)
\x y -> (id :: Reader r a -> Reader r a) (ap x y)
  :: (r -> a1 -> a) -> (r -> a1) -> Reader r a
```

in what ghc recognizes as the synonym `Reader r a`