# GHCi syntax to display specializations of type class functions

Tags: haskell, syntax, ghci

After the command `:set -XTypeApplications` we can use GHCi to to display
specializations of type class functions of a specific instance.

A simple example:

```
:type fmap @Maybe
```

GHCi replies with

```
fmap @Maybe :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

Question: How is the syntax for instances with data types with two (or more) polymorphic parameters?

In the *Functor* class these are instances like `Either a`, `((,) a` or `((->) r)`.
I tried the following examples, but all of them are rejected by GHCi:

```
:t fmap @Either 
:t fmap @(Either a)
:t fmap @(Either a b)
:t forall a. fmap @(Either a)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999199/how-can-i-get-the-type-of-a-polymorphic-function-for-a-specific-type-class-insta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

```
> :t fmap @(Either a)
```

but that would require that `a` be in scope, which is not.
For that, we would need the type-level abstraction

```
> -- pseudo code
> :t \ (a :: *) -> fmap @(Either a)
forall a b c . (b -> c) -> Either a b -> Either a c
```

but this is found only in Core.

We can however use a custom, dummy type `A` for this:

```
> data A -- don't declare instances for this
> :t fmap @(Either A)
forall b c. (b -> c) -> Either A b -> Either A c
```

---

Simpler alternative, using partial type annotations.

```
> :t fmap @(Either _)
fmap @(Either _) :: (a -> b) -> Either t a -> Either t b
```

Comment: I like the syntax with the underscore (_)